# Contains equivalent in segmentation lists

Tags: rules-engine, segmentation, segmented-list

Implements rules for segmentation lists. I have a requirement that forces me to use the contains method on a string. Unfortunately, this feature is not supported. Has anyone managed to make an equivalent of this method?

Answer (score 1):

The xConnect search supports only a specific subset of queryable conditions, and it is unlikely that a workaround exists.

Interestingly, the [supported search method documentation for 10.0](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/sitecore-experience-platform/en/supported-methods-and-operators-for-xconnect-search.html) says that partial text search is not supported when using Azure Search provider, which implies that it is supported with Solr, but the code sample doesn't make any sense:

```
client.Contacts.Where(c => c.TextMatch("Mar"))
```

*(you can ask sitecore support whether it is a typo or not btw)*

And you could try solving this in a different way, for example by evaluating the facet value when it is saved using [calculated facets](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-calculated-facet.html).
Using calculated facets you can check if a facet property contains a predefined string (using normal `.Contains()` method) and save the result to a new bool facet property, and check that property in the segment instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using *string* data type for the Comparison variable instead of *StringOperationType*.

[image]

and in Sitecore, for the Comparison variable, you can create a custom multilist item folder at path /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions

[image]

and then refer this to rule definition item:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the contains function is not supported by indexes and an error occurs when trying to use it. That's why I asked this question.